# Why will this not compile

Tags: swift, linux, webkit

Newest Ubuntu (20) and swift (5.6).

Test.swift
Import WebKit

```
Var WKit = WebKit()
```

swiftc test.swift
error: no such module ‘WebKit‘

I used apt-get libwebkit2gtk perhaps this is the suspect?

Comment: Because WebKit is not part of Swift for Linux I assume.

Answer (score 0):

WebKit is not part of the Swift language or standard library. WebKit is a separate framework bundled with the OS that's only available on iOS and macOS. Hence, you cannot use it on Linux.

For more information, see the [WebKit documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit).

Comment: Thank you. Looks like a path issue as import OS also not working

Comment: I’m still thinking path issue; however,
my understanding the package for WebKit ported linux is  libwebkit2gtk which I successfully installed.